# transform and replace values in existing column IF multiple matching values exist using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets: A and B.

If dataset A's `year`, `ID`, `delivery`, `type`, and `vendor` columns all match with dataset B's `Tags`, `ID`, `qtr`, `TYPE`, and `msc` columns, then I want to replace the `project_id` of the matching row in dataset A with the `Project Name` from the corresponding row in dataset B. Otherwise, I don't want to change the `project_id` in A.

dataset A:

```
Year    ID  deliv   Gen type    vendor  project_id
2022    BR  Q2 2022 L   aa      d       BR2 aa1 Q2 2022 - L
2022    BR  Q2 2022 L   dd      d       BR2 dd1 Q2 2022 - L
2022    BR  Q2 2022 L   dd      d       BR2 dd2 Q2 2022 - L
2022    BR  Q3 2022 L   bb      d       BR2 bb1 Q3 2022 - L
2022    BR  Q4 2022 L   aa      d       BR2 aa1 Q4 2022 - L
2022    BR  Q4 2022 L   dd      nd      BR2 dd1 Q4 2022 - L
```

dataset B:

```
Project Name          Tags  ID      qtr     TYPE    msc NUM
BB H_AA01 Q4 2022     2022  BOLOL   Q4 2022 aa      d   01
BR2 H_DD_nd02 Q4 2022 2022  BR      Q4 2022 dd      nd  02
BR2 BB01 Q3.2022      2022  BR      Q3 2022 bb      d   01
BR2 H_DD01 Q2 2022    2022  BR      Q2 2022 dd      d   01
BR2 H_DD02 Q2 2022    2022  BR      Q2 2022 dd      d   02
BR2 H_AA01 Q2 2022    2022  BR      Q2 2022 aa      d   01
```

desired result:

```
Year    ID  delivery    Gen type    vendor  project_id
2022    BR  Q2 2022     L   aa      d       BR2 H_AA01 Q2 2022
2022    BR  Q2 2022     L   dd      d       BR2 H_DD01 Q2 2022
2022    BR  Q2 2022     L   dd      d       BR2 H_DD02 Q2 2022
2022    BR  Q3 2022     L   bb      d       BR2 BB01 Q3.2022
2022    BR  Q4 2022     L   aa      d       BR2 aa1 Q4 2022 - L
2022    BR  Q4 2022     L   dd      nd      BR2 H_DD_nd02 Q4 2022
```

Here is my current attempt:

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df_A, df_B[['Project Name', 'Tags', 'ID', 'qtr', 'TYPE', 'msc']], 
                     how='left', 
                     left_on=['Year', 'ID', 'delivery', 'type', 'vendor'], 
                     right_on=['Tags', 'ID', 'qtr', 'TYPE', 'msc'])

# Replacing 'project_id' in A with 'Project Name' from B where there is a match
df_merged['project_id'] = df_merged['Project Name'].combine_first(df_merged['project_id'])

# Dropping unnecessary columns from the merge
df_final = df_merged.drop(['Project Name', 'Tags', 'qtr', 'TYPE', 'msc'], axis=1)
```

However, the above script blows up my dataset, creating unnecessary rows and multiple columns.

The final output should have the same enumber of rows and columns as the original dataset. The only difference is that the `project_id` column is being updated. How do I properly perform this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can try :

```
lcols = ["Year", "ID", "delivery", "type", "vendor"]
rcols = ["Tags", "ID", "qtr", "TYPE", "msc"]

out = (
    pd.merge(
        df_A, df_B,
        left_on=[*lcols, df_A.groupby(lcols).cumcount()],
        right_on=[*rcols, df_B.groupby(rcols).cumcount()],
        how="left"
    )
    .assign(project_id= lambda x: x["Project Name"].fillna(x["project_id"]))
    [df_A.columns]
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   Year  ID delivery Gen type vendor             project_id
0  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   aa      d     BR2 H_AA01 Q2 2022
1  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   dd      d     BR2 H_DD01 Q2 2022
2  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   dd      d     BR2 H_DD02 Q2 2022
3  2022  BR  Q3 2022   L   bb      d       BR2 BB01 Q3.2022
4  2022  BR  Q4 2022   L   aa      d    BR2 aa1 Q4 2022 - L
5  2022  BR  Q4 2022   L   dd     nd  BR2 H_DD_nd02 Q4 2022

[6 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Nice use of `cumcount`, but you should point out that this code relies on the rows being in the same order in `df_A` and `df_B`

Comment: Thank you @Timeless - I will see if this works on my dataset!

Comment: Thanks Nick ;) but I don't think I made an assumption. @Lynn, you're welcome.

Comment: Sure you did, try swapping rows 4 and 5 in `df_B` and you will see that you get a different result

Comment: We could also argue that if 4/5 were swapped in `df_B`, OP might claim a different result.

Comment: That's my whole point. This gets a different result based on the duplicate row ordering in `df_A` and `df_B`. Not that you can do anything about it, just that it happens.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is arising because of these two entries in `df_A`:

```
2022    BR  Q2 2022 L   dd      d       BR2 dd1 Q2 2022 - L
2022    BR  Q2 2022 L   dd      d       BR2 dd2 Q2 2022 - L
```

and in `df_B`:

```
2022    BR  Q2 2022     L   dd      d       BR2 H_DD01 Q2 2022
2022    BR  Q2 2022     L   dd      d       BR2 H_DD02 Q2 2022
```

In your merge, these have exactly the same merge condition, and so you get 4 rows in your output instead of the 2 you want:

```
1  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   dd      d     BR2 H_DD02 Q2 2022
2  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   dd      d     BR2 H_DD01 Q2 2022
3  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   dd      d     BR2 H_DD02 Q2 2022
4  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   dd      d     BR2 H_DD01 Q2 2022
```

Without any further means of identifying which `Project Name` in `df_B` corresponds to which `project_id` in `df_A`, you will always have this problem. You can resolve this issue using `drop_duplicates` e.g.

```
df_final = df_final.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

which will give you:

```
   Year  ID delivery Gen type vendor             project_id
0  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   aa      d     BR2 H_AA01 Q2 2022
1  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   dd      d     BR2 H_DD02 Q2 2022
2  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   dd      d     BR2 H_DD01 Q2 2022
3  2022  BR  Q3 2022   L   bb      d       BR2 BB01 Q3.2022
4  2022  BR  Q4 2022   L   aa      d    BR2 aa1 Q4 2022 - L
5  2022  BR  Q4 2022   L   dd     nd  BR2 H_DD_nd02 Q4 2022
```

You can also use the `cumcount` solution proposed in @Timeless answer as a workaround for this, but the result you get in either case will depend on the ordering of rows in `df_A` and `df_B`. For example, if rows 4 & 5 in `df_B` were swapped, you would get this output from their code instead:

```
   Year  ID delivery Gen type vendor             project_id
0  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   aa      d     BR2 H_AA01 Q2 2022
1  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   dd      d     BR2 H_DD02 Q2 2022
2  2022  BR  Q2 2022   L   dd      d     BR2 H_DD01 Q2 2022
3  2022  BR  Q3 2022   L   bb      d       BR2 BB01 Q3.2022
4  2022  BR  Q4 2022   L   aa      d    BR2 aa1 Q4 2022 - L
5  2022  BR  Q4 2022   L   dd     nd  BR2 H_DD_nd02 Q4 2022
```

This may be fine for your purposes, but it is something to be aware of. Ideally, you should have something unique that identifies each project and is present in both `df_A` and `df_B` (it can be as simple as a number), otherwise you will continue to run into this issue in the future.

Comment: thank you Nick, I will look at this soln

Comment: @Lynn no worries - I hope you find it useful.